# How to write manifest (XML) for a touch app in eclipse?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-manifest

I am writing an app in eclipse 'Singletouch Example'. I am referring to  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html. I am unable to write the correct XML code. Either it is showing "Unfortunately (your app) has stopped.” error or code error.

Code:

```
package de.vogella.android.touch.single;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SingleTouchActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));
        }
    }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.helloworld"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="8"
  android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<application
   android:debuggable="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the correct Activity and package in manifest.
Change

`android:name=".MainActivity"` to

`android:name=".SingleTouchActivity"` and
package(**package="com.example.helloworld" to package="de.vogella.android.touch.single"**) in AndroidManifest.xml

You can get the source code for single touch from [here](http://www.vogella.com/code/de.vogella.android.touch.single/codestartpage.html)!

[image: Project Structure]

Is this the package and class you are using?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well i tried it and still it is showing " Unfortunately TouchProject has stopped" . I think it is because of the incorrect xml code? Please help.

Comment: Is this the package and class you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

> ```
>    <activity android:name="SingleTouchActivity"
>               android:label="@string/app_name">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> ```

Try this xml file

> ```
> <RelativeLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent">
> ```

```
<com.vogella.android.multitouch.MultitouchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well i tried it and still it is showing " Unfortunately TouchProject has stopped" . I think it is because of the incorrect xml code? Please help.

Comment: I think Android doesn't provide any MultitouchView. So if you want to make any app like this, then you need to use upper type of View. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Hey ,I still cant fix the " Unfortunately TouchProject has stopped" error. Where do you think is the error in the code ?